# How to read in textfile using expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I imported 'expo-file-system' to utilize `FileSystem`.

The code below is the way I am trying to read my text file.

```js
render() {
  const fileInfo = FileSystem.readAsStringAsync('../contents/round1.txt');
  console.log(fileInfo);

  return (
    <View style={style.backgroundStyle}>
      <Text>ReParty Logo </Text>
      <Text>{fileInfo}</Text>
      {/* <Text>Here{round1Text}</Text> */}
      <Text style={style.roundNum}>1</Text>            
    </View>
  )
}
```

How can I read the information from the text file and display the text file information on the screen?
Thank you!

Comment: As from the code above, I understand you are trying to read a file from your source code in execution time. The expo FileSystem aims to read files from your device, not from your source code.

Comment: React provides a way to read static files: https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#static-non-image-resources

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier in the comments, to read an odd file (not a module import, not a json file) from your source code tree in runtime is not easy.

You will need both `expo-asset` and `expo-file-system` for this to work in Expo:

`npx expo install expo-asset expo-file-system`

Rebuild your device build with the new installed Expo modules:

`npx expo run:android --device`

The trick is to use `Asset` to get a runtime local URI to your source code file and then read it with `readAsStringAsync`:

```js
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";
import { readAsStringAsync } from "expo-file-system";

async function readFile() {
    const [{ localUri }] = await Asset.loadAsync(require("../../../assets/file.txt"));

    console.log("localUri:", localUri);

    if (localUri) {
      readAsStringAsync(localUri).then((contents) => {
        console.log("CONTENTS", contents);
      });
    }
}
```

As the `.txt` file extension is unknown to Metro and also to Babel (if that is the case), we need to tell them to recognize that file extension:

Add this line `config.resolver.assetExts.push("txt");` to your metro.config.js.

And the new extension to babel.config.js:

```js
const MODULE_RESOLVER = [
  "module-resolver",
  {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".native.ts", ".native.tsx", ".android.ts", ".android.tsx", ".ios.ts", ".ios.tsx", ".txt"],
    alias: {
      "@src": "./src",
    },
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. As nobody answered, the only way for me was to translate my textfile to a json file, which will be parsed automatically.

[What is the proper way to bundle a textfile with the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63104357/what-is-the-proper-way-to-bundle-a-textfile-with-the-app)