# What is the proper way to bundle a textfile with the app

Tags: react-native, expo

Using expo, I need to provide a text-file with data (a word-dictionary) to the app.
How do I provide that and how do I read it into memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I translated my textfile to a json-formatted content. This can very easy be used. The json is parsed automatically.

```
import data from './assets/woerter.json';
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately loading static assets not among those supported by default (e.g. json) is a bit convoluted in react native. Often it's easier to convert to json, anyway this is the general solution:

1. First you need to tell the bundler (Metro) to bundle the files of interest, create a `metro.config.js` file in your root with this:

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');

const configs = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
configs.resolver.assetExts.push('txt')

module.exports = configs;
```

you probably need to `npm i @expo/metro-config` as well.

2. Now using [Expo Asset](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/asset/) (`npx expo install expo-asset`) you have to download the file of interest from the bundle to the file system, so you can get access to it:

```js
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";

const { localUri } = await Asset.fromModule(require('/src/data/your-dict.txt')).downloadAsync();
```

3. And using [Expo FileSystem](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/) (`npx expo install expo-file-system`) you can load your file content

```js
import { readAsStringAsync } from "expo-file-system";

const dictString = await readAsStringAsync(localUri);
console.log("My Dictionary:", dictString);
```